# Will uTouch work on a Dell inspiron duo?

Tags: multi-touch

I installed Ubuntu (netbook and desktop) + uTouch on my brand new Dell inspiron duo (hybrid netbook/tablet). But uTouch doenot seem to work on my Dell? Can anyone help on how to get it work? Thx in advance

Rolf

Answer (score 2):

Multi-touch is not working on the Duo now hopefully it will in 11.04. This is the guide to set up the duo for general touch screen. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1658635